# $t^2y'' - 3ty' + 4y = 0$, how do you solve for $y$ in terms of $t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I know that I have to use method of reduction, but I'm not sure how to arrive at a solution.

All help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try $y = t^\lambda$

Comment: Or $y = e^{t}$ and check for what $a$ this solves the equation. Fore more details google Euler's Equation

Comment: this equation is an instance of euler's equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Cauchy–Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) which is solved by the substitution $y=t^r$.
$$0=t^2r(r-1)r^{r-2}-3trt^{r-1}+4t^r=t^r(r^2-4r+4)=t^r(r-2)^2$$
As you have a root of multiplicty $2$, your solution will be of the form
$$y=C_1t^2+C_2t^2\ln t$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ t^2 y'' - 3t y' + 4\lambda y = 0 \tag{1}$$
is a Sturm-Liouville-type differential equation. To solve it, you can follow what is sketched in the paragraph *Rodrigues' formula* [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_orthogonal_polynomials), reaching $R(x)=x^3,W(x)=x$. When $\lambda=1$, by setting $y(t)=t^2 f(t)$ we get rid of the $y$ term in $(1)$, reaching:
$$ t^3 (f'(t) + t f''(t)) = 0, $$
or just:
$$ f'(t) + t\,f''(t) = 0, \tag{1}$$
from which it follows that:
$$ f'(t) = \frac{K}{t},\qquad f(t)= C+K\log t,\qquad \color{red}{y(t) = Ct^2 + Kt^2 \log t}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I missed a "trick" from my solution..$$f''+\frac{1}{t}f'\implies tf'' + f' = (tf')'$$ .. +1!

Answer (score 0):

trial solution $y = t^\alpha v$
$$
t^{\alpha+2}v'' + (2\alpha - 3)t^{\alpha+1}v' + \left[\alpha(\alpha-1)-2\alpha + 4\right]t^\alpha v = 0
$$
lets try get rid of the last term and hope all other terms are easier afterwards..
$$
\alpha(\alpha-1)-2\alpha + 4 = \alpha^2 - 4\alpha + 4 = 0\implies \alpha = 2
$$
now we have reduced to

$$
t^4v'' + t^3v' = 0
$$ 
which is
$$
v'' + \frac{1}{t}v' = 0\tag{*}
$$
we can reduce by setting $v' = u$
then
$$
u' + \frac{1}{t}u =0
$$

$\textbf{edit}$

As in another Jacks solution..we can write Eq(*) as
$$
tv'' + v' = (tv')' = 0 \implies tv' = C_1
$$